# How to encrypt data with RSA Public Key in OpenSSL 3.0 C++?

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I want to encrypt data using RSA_public_encrypt function however documentation says that this function is deprecated since OpenSSL 3.0, so my question is, if we no longer do it with RSA_public_encrypt what is the modern way of doing this?

Comment: It says what to replace it with on the same page that says it's deprecated.

Comment: oh EVP_PKEY_encrypt... I must be blind, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the man page for [`RSA_public_encrypt`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/RSA_public_encrypt.html), under "Description" is the information:

> Both of the functions described on this page are deprecated.
> Applications should instead use EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init_ex(3),
> EVP_PKEY_encrypt(3), EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init_ex(3) and
> EVP_PKEY_decrypt(3).

It's probably a good idea for most software to use these new functions because the world appears to be transitioning from RSA-based cryptography to elliptic curve-based cryptography and possibly to even newer quantum-resistant cryptography, and the new functions are agnostic as to the public key technology being used.